# Microsoft Expression - OutputPreviewWindow not working

Tags: c#, expression

I am trying to build a simple test example that uses my webcam and outputs to a WIndowsFormHost. This is actually taken from the sample code but I am not sure why it's not working. My webcam's LED is lit up so I guess that means my webcam isn't the problem.

Can anyone help me out with this? This is my sample code.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        job = new LiveJob();

        deviceSource = job.AddDeviceSource(videoDevs.Count > 0 ? videoDevs[1] : null, audioDevs.Count > 0 ? audioDevs[0] : null);
        job.ActivateSource(deviceSource);
        job.ApplyPreset(LivePresets.VC1HighSpeedBroadband16x9);
        job.StartEncoding();
        job.OutputPreviewWindow = new PreviewWindow(new HandleRef(displayPanel, displayPanel.Handle));
        //Console.Read();
        //job.StopEncoding();
    }
```

Also, I get this weird error that says HREF COMException when I try to put job.StartEncoding() in a button. Anyone can tell me what this error means?

[image: COMException]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solutions to my question.

```
private string Broadcast_Webcam()
    {
        if (_job == null)
        {
            v_Device = EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Video);
            a_Device = EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Audio);

            _job = new LiveJob();
            _source = _job.AddDeviceSource(v_Device.Count > 0 ? v_Device[1] : null,                       a_Device.Count > 0 ? a_Device[0] : null);
            _job.ActivateSource(_source);
        }

        if (_job != null)
        {
            _job.ApplyPreset(LivePresets.VC1Broadband4x3);

            PullBroadcastPublishFormat format = new PullBroadcastPublishFormat();
            format.BroadcastPort = 8080;
            format.MaximumNumberOfConnections = 2;
            _job.PublishFormats.Add(format);
            _job.StartEncoding();

        }
        return "Webcam service has been started";
    }
```

This will work without a problem.

The second question which was a constant error of COMEXCEPTION. The method to solve it is via

```
_job.StopEncoding();
_job.Dispose();
```

I forgot to stop the encoding process before disposing it, causing a exception.